# access_token for Facebook Registering Achievement

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I saw almost all posts about getting access_token, but nothing seems to be helpful for me.
I typed in Graph API Explorer  -

```
"oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

where:

`APP_ID` : my app id (15 digits)

`APP_SECRET` : my app secret (from settings->main)

with empty `access_token` line,

In advanced settings of the app - web application
Tried to refresh App_secret several times - did not help.

Sandbox Mode - disabled.
Integration with facebook - Native Android App.

And what I've got as a result of all above

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not test this in the Graph API Explorer. It didn't return any JSON, instead you have to get the content from the -

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

You can test it by simply running it in your browser, you'll get the result in format-

> access_token=APP_ID|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX